# Javascript : pass function as variable and execute it

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript and for that i am creating a simple effects library with fadein fadeout etc functionalities .Everything works ok but it dosent execute the function that i am passing in to execute when the effect is done.

I get the error

```
element[3] is not a function
```

my code:

```
//add the effect 
jlqAddEffect(document.getElementById("mainBoard"),"fadeout",10,function(){
    alert("done"); //->>>I dont get this executed when the effect is done
});

//EFFECTS
var effectElements=new Array();
function jlqAddEffect(element,type,speed,func)
{
    var effect=[element,type,setInterval(function(){jlqUpdateEffect(effect);},speed),func];//->>Here i pass the function in the 3d element of the array
    effectElements.push(effect);
    jlqInitEffect(effect);
}

function jlqInitEffect(element)
{
    if(element[1]=="fadein")element[0].style.opacity=0;
    if(element[1]=="fadeout")element[0].style.opacity=1;
}
function jlqUpdateEffect(element)
{
    var done=false;
    if(element[1]=="fadein"){
        if(parseFloat(element[0].style.opacity)<1){
            element[0].style.opacity=parseFloat(element[0].style.opacity)+0.01;
        }
        else done=true;
    }
    if(element[1]=="fadeout"){
        if(parseFloat(element[0].style.opacity)>0){
            element[0].style.opacity=parseFloat(element[0].style.opacity)-0.01;
        }
        else done=true;
    }
    if(done){
        alert("effect done");//->>I get this executed when the effect is done
        element[3](); // ->>here it should be calling the function but it gives me the error
        clearInterval(element[2]);
        effectElements.splice(effectElements.indexOf(element),1);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Ohh i feel silly now .The problem wasn't on the code i posted .
I am puting two effect ,one when the page loads and one when it closes
in the one when the page loads i wasn't passing an function i was jsut had this

```
jlqAddEffect(document.getElementById("mainBoard"),"fadein",10);
```

And since i wasn't passing a function elements[3] wasn't a function...

Comment: Works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/nZpSs/

Comment: what happens when you do a `console.log(element[3]);`?

Comment: you pass `jlqUpdateEffect(effect)` to `setIntervall`. But there is no `effect` yet.

Comment: @redreggae Doesn't matter, there will be when the function runs.

Comment: @Juhana - Not in your fiddle - the variable hasn't been initialised yet when you call the function. (You get a bunch of errors in the console.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Is it browser-specific? I get unrelated errors in Chrome, but there's no problem with the `effect` variable.

Comment: Yuck, arrays instead of object :-( In any case, you're paying in the results of calling setInterval. Oh, no your not-misread... See? Arrays :-(

Comment: I used Chrome. `effectElements` is still `undefined` when the function is first run. You can avoid this by moving the initial call to `jlqAddEffect()` to the end.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yeah, ok, we're talking about different things. The `setInterval()` call isn't related to `effectElements`.

Answer (score 1):

There were two problems when I tested it in Chrome:

- You call the `jlqAddEffect()` function before the `effectElements` variable has been initialised to an array, which leads to errors when you try to `effectElements.push(effect);`. Easily fixed by moving the `jlqAddEffect()` call to the end of your code.
- Your animation never actually completes, because JavaScript's floating point arithmetic (and/or something weird in the handling of the `opacity` property) prevents the opacity ever getting all the way down to `0`. It gets down to `0.009999999999999247` and then gets "stuck". You can fix this by testing whether the opacity is greater than `0.01` instead of greater than `0`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nZpSs/1/